# Add a break every N characters in an HTML string

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

## Question background:

I need to 'textwrap' an HTML string such that the `<br>` elements are applied to *only* the *text* within the HTML string.

I can apply the styling to text strings (if only *one* type of styling is required).

However, appending styles to this string any further confuses the actual text with the styling tags (obviously).

## Example:

```
s = 'Here is a string'
styled_str = styling_func1(s)
print(styled_str)

#        >>> "<font color='black'>Here</font> is a string"

styled_str = syling_func2(styled_str)
print(styled_str)

#        >>> "<font <br>color='black'>Here</font> is a string"
```

As you can see, the `<br>` gets stuck within the tags if the `styling_func2` operates on a string.

The actual function I need is one that adds `<br>` elements every ~N characters or words, without causing these conflicts.

## Attempts at a solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic polariton laser<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span>not<span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span>  =========  Publisher Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the AMD Annals initiative<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span><span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

# How to keep the previous tags while inserting these breaks?
"<br>".join(textwrap.wrap(soup.get_text(), 50))
```

## Example Test Data:

string input:

```
<html><body><p>Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic polariton laser<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span>not<span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span>  =========  Publisher Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the AMD Annals initiative<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span><span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span></p></body></html>
```

i.e.

Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic polariton laser **.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has** not **been fixed in the paper.**  =========  Publisher Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the AMD Annals initiative **.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has** **been fixed in the paper.**

(where bold would be red)

Desired output:

```
<html><body><p>Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic <br>polariton laser<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has <br>been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF <br>versions of this paper. The error has </span>not<span style="color:red"> been <br>fixed in the paper.</span>  =========  Publisher <br>Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease <br>in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the <br>AMD Annals initiative<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this <br>article has been published and is linked from the <br>HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span><span style="color:red"> <br>been fixed in the paper.</span></p></body></html>
```

i.e.

Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic polariton

laser **.. A correction to this article has**

**been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF**

**versions of this paper. The error has** not **been**

**fixed in the paper.**  =========  Publisher

Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease

in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the

AMD Annals initiative **.. A correction to this**

**article has been published and is linked from the**

**HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has**

**been fixed in the paper.**

Comment: There are lots of things to consider when text wrapping - font size, non-proportional characters, inter-character gap, and these can change throughout the text with different markup tags. The thing that knows about all of this is the browser that renders text to the screen. And its controlled by CSS. Why not add styles instead of manually adding <br >?

Comment: This is for an application which *doesn't have** any css capabilities.  Specifically for showing small snippets of text in a graphing package. There are onyl a very small subset of html tags that work with it, but `<span>` and `<br>` tags work. *I know this probably isn't tecvhnically true, due to the use of inline html styling, but I don't know much of the internals for the package that handles the input.

Comment: I made decent styling of these strings by using `<div>`s - before I realized that they weren't handled by the package I am using, so I have had to revert to these `<span>` and `<br>` tags now.

Answer (score 0):

The approximate brute-force way, if we consider there is no tag encapsulation (otherwise, please do tell), could be:

```
def put_tags_every_N(_input, _tag, _n):
    _k = 0
    _in_tag = False
    _len = len(_input)
    _i = 0
    while  _i < _len:
        _c = _input[_i]
        if _c == '<':
            _in_tag = True
        elif _c == '>':
            _in_tag = False
        if not _in_tag and _c != '>':
            _k += 1
            if _k % _n == 0:
                _input = _input[:_i+1]+_tag+_input[_i+1:]
                _len += len(_tag)
        _i += 1
    return _input

def put_tags_every_N_nowordcut(_input, _tag, _n):
    _k = 0
    _in_tag = False
    _position_past = False
    _len = len(_input)
    _i = 0
    while  _i < _len:
        _c = _input[_i]
        if _c == '<':
            _in_tag = True
        elif _c == '>':
            _in_tag = False
        if not _in_tag and _c != '>':
            _k += 1
            if _k % _n == 0:
                _position_past = True
            if _position_past and (_input[_i+1] in ('<', '.') or _input[_i] == ' '):
                _input = _input[:_i+1]+_tag+_input[_i+1:]
                _len += len(_tag)
                _position_past = False
                _k = 0
        _i += 1
    return _input

_tmp_input = '<html><body><p>Author Correction: Hybrid organic-inorganic polariton laser<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span>not<span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span>  =========  Publisher Correction: Predictors of chronic kidney disease in type 1 diabetes: a longitudinal study from the AMD Annals initiative<span style="color:red">.. A correction to this article has been published and is linked from the HTML and PDF versions of this paper. The error has </span><span style="color:red"> been fixed in the paper.</span></p></body></html>'
# print(put_tags_every_N(_input=_tmp_input, _tag='<br>', _n=50))
# print(put_tags_every_N(_input=_tmp_input, _tag='<br>', _n=5))
print(put_tags_every_N_nowordcut(_input=_tmp_input, _tag='<br>', _n=50))
# print(put_tags_every_N_nowordcut(_input=_tmp_input, _tag='<br>', _n=5))
```

(put_tags_every_N just put the _tag every _n character, whereas put_tags_every_N_nowordcut put the _tag at the first opportunity once it counted _n characters in order to preserve words, and not put a single in-between-words space at the beginning of the next line.)